# Will it place 0 or \0 at the end?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

in char arr[8] what is arr[3] whether it will be treated as non string array as they are characters (initializes to zero) or string array.

```
char arr[8]={'a','b','c'}//what will be arr[3] and onwards \0 or 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare an array with an explicit size and initialize it, any members of the array not explicitly initialized are set to 0.

This is specified in section 6.7.9p21 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there
>   are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a
>   string literal used to initialize an array of known size  than  there 
>   are  elements  in  the  array,  the  remainder  of  the  aggregate 
>   shall  be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static
>   storage duration.

So `arr[3]`, `arr[4]`, `arr[5]`, `arr[6]`, and `arr[7]` will all be 0.

Note also that 0 and `'\0'` are two different representations in source code for the same value.